# My laptop internal speakers produce no sound since installing. OS=Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. I was using Windows 8.1 beforehand and the laptop internal speakers worked just fine. But now since I have installed Ubuntu my laptop speakers produce no sound at all.
I have "Acer Extensa 5235" laptop with Conexant CX20561 (Hermosa) with PulseAudio server and Alsa base.

The sound is not disabled from Bios. I do not know how to get the internal speakers working.
Below is the result of        aplay -L command
$aplay -L

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
equal
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, CX20561 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: Both of the answers do not work.

Answer (score 0):

PulseAudio controls underlying ALSA-level volume controls. Open a terminal. Enter `alsamixer` and press the Enter key.

You will now see a user interface like below.

[image: Alsamixer Interface]

Select your correct sound card using F6. Mute/Unmute with the “M” key. An “MM” means muted, and “OO” means unmuted.

This was the problem I had once.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to what Babbzzz answered is to use GNOME ALSA Mixer. It's the exact same thing as the terminal program `alsamixer` but it is a GUI version.

Simply run `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer` in Terminal (or search for/install it in the Software Center/Synaptic.) Once installed you should be able to launch it from the HUD menu.

It provides all the same functions of ALSA Mixer, just in a GUI form - some people may prefer this:

[image]